# code doesnt run when using if __name__ == '__main__'

Tags: python, sublimetext3

When running any code in sublime, pycharm or spyder I always get this message and the code stops.
Code I'm currently using: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gNjci.jpg

RuntimeError:
An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

```
    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable..
```

When adding if **name** == '**main**': in front of the code it crashes:https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTMNg.jpg

But when I run the same code in python cmd it works just fine: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYOUy.jpg

I have a 5 5600g apu and python 3.10 if that helps

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Normally the main guard comes after the import statements. Not sure if that is your issue here or not

Comment: [Please do not upload images – and especially not videos – of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) You can [edit] your question to add a [mre], i.e. the minimal code and steps to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit]I saw your video and your code doesn't crash, the process just ends. You can just add sleep to see the browser work.

This worked for me:

```py
from multiprocessing import freeze_support
from time import sleep

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()
    import undetected_chromedriver as uc
    driver = uc.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://nowsecure.nl')
    sleep(10)
```

Maybe you can omit `freeze_support()` in your case.

And as someone suggests, I would move `import undetected_chromedriver as uc` to the top, though.